# IllegalArgumentException : Illegal character in query

Tags: android, json, url, illegalargumentexception, illegal-characters

There is an Illegal character in my url and I think it is '|'

**Stack Trace**

```
04-19 23:08:02.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17068): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 76: https://graph.facebook.com/150205375156742/feed?access_token=520625188052604|GsCYVGBJKs5N_O1AX9XrrsulrWc
```

I went through some of the previously asked questions and so far I have tried these 2 solutions :

```
1) tried to replace | with %7C or %20 
2) safeUrl = URLEncoder.encode("https://graph.facebook.com/150205375156742/feed?access_token=520625188052604|GsCYVGBJKs5N_O1AX9XrrsulrWc", "UTF-8");
```

And none of them works for me.

Comment: A `'|'` is not a reserved character in a URI and should be legal. (See [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), section 2.2). How do you know it is not? If you're getting an exception, please post the stack trace.

Comment: I am not very sure about it.If it is so,can you guide me with the right solution.

Comment: Check your url in normal browser for its validity

Comment: What method are you calling that results in the posted exception?

Comment: parsing this url using json

Comment: I assume you mean that you are going to parse the document read from that url. However, the exception is presumably happening before the site is accessed. What line of your code is generating the exception? That's what we need to see to be able to help you.

Comment: ` HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]); // getting exception here '